# C++ How to display/print a string object? cout << int works, cout << string not

Tags: c++, string, class, object, cout

I ran into an issue google could not solve. Why is that cout works for an int object but not a string object in the following program?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass {
    string val;
public:
    //Normal constructor.
    MyClass(string i) {
        val= i;
        cout << "Inside normal constructor\n";
    }
    //Copy constructor 
    MyClass(const MyClass &o) {
        val = o.val;
        cout << "Inside copy constructor.\n";
    }
    string getval() {return val; }
};
void display(MyClass ob)
{
    cout << ob.getval() << endl;    //works for int but not strings
}
int main()
{
    MyClass a("Hello");
    display(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? Why don't you make `getval()` const?

Comment: Works for me. What is your `seen` output and `expected` output. In what way should they be different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must include the `string` header to get the overloaded `operator<<`.

Also you might want to return a `const string&` instead of a `string` from `getval`, change your constructor to accept a `const string&` instead of a `string`, and change `display` to accept a `const MyClass& ob` to avoid needless copying.

Comment: Shouldn't (most) compilers be able to perform copy elision in that case? Just wondering, I heard many opinions on returning by value and letting the compiler optimise or returning by constant reference.

Comment: @Shelling I may be old fashioned, but I prefer to go with `const T&` when I don't want to make a copy and I don't want to change the outer object from inside the function. This both makes your intentions clear and removes the possibility of compiler stupidity. It also keeps you from accidentally doing stuff that you never meant to do (like changing the parameter in the function, which would make the compiler not elide).

Comment: @Shelling that, and it makes your debug builds (where maximum optimisation is not enabled) work and not be amazingly slow.

Comment: granted, I only thought about release builds in that moment. But, if I return, or pass, a constant reference from or to a function, instead of a copy that would be elided in release builds, wouldn't that make the release builds a little bit slower? (Sure, it's probably not noticable) Or am I just trusting the compiler too much? :D

Comment: @Shelling what? Why would passing by const reference be slower? I don't think I understood the question. And, in my opinion, one always trusts the compiler too much :)

Comment: When I pass a const reference, the compiler would need to dereference every access to that, which should add a bit overhead compared to an elided copy (I honestly don't know if the compiler optimises here and, in the end, produces the same output). I hope I don't write nonsense here, it's getting pretty late :D

Comment: @Shelling no, that's not how references work, they don't dereference like pointers. They're just the variable, like a variable name. Besides, what else would an elided copy turn into? I would assume it turns them into something that works like a const reference.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie thanks Seth!! But why is that >> needs to be overloaded for strings?

Comment: @Techno because the `iostream` library is independent of the `string` library so `iostream` doesn't know anything about it; i.e. `iostream` doesn't know anything about `string` but `string` knows about `iostream`, so it's the one who has to define how to use itself with an `ostream`.

Comment: @Techno if this answer answered your question, please click the check mark beside the top left to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is working for you or if you have fixed it but I just was working on this... for your cout you must put the line as cout << "insert string here" << endl; You're not putting the second << after the string. Hope this helps!